# Trying to save a clone of an array in a txt file but returns NULL

Tags: java, arrays, text

I am making an app that keeps username and scores from a game in a txt file. The concept is that when it writes a new username and score to the txt file it should open the `.txt` file, read it and then make a clone of it adding a new uername and score entry in the txt file.

I am thinking of making this with 2 object arrays. The first is the one that is read in and the new will be the one is writen which will have one more entry.

So if `player[i]` is readen `player[i+1]` should be writen with new entry.

I am giving u the code below!

```
private Player[] myplayer=null;
private Player[] mynewplayer=null;

//open Players.txt
      int i;
      int n;
      String filename="players.txt";
      try
      {

         FileReader fp=new FileReader(filename);
         BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(fp);
         n=Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
         myplayer=new Player[n];
         int x=n+1;
         mynewplayer=new Player[x];
         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
             String s=bf.readLine();
             String user="",score="";
             user=s.substring(0,s.indexOf(","));
             s=s.substring(s.indexOf(",")+1);
             score=s;
             myplayer[i]=new Player(user,Double.parseDouble(score));

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                     mynewplayer[i]= myplayer[i];
            }
            mynewplayer[x]=new Player(Username,Double.parseDouble(score));
         }

         bf.close();
         fp.close();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception was "+e.getMessage());
        }



    //----------------------------------WRITE mytxt!-------------
      n=myplayer.length;
      try
      {
         filename="players.txt";
         FileWriter fp=new FileWriter(filename);
         fp.write(""+n+"\n");
         for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)
           fp.write(""+mynewplayer[i]+"\n");

         fp.close();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception was "+e.getMessage());
        }
    //----------------------------------WRITE mytxt!-----------

    //Get on Message
      String s="";
      for(i=0;i<mynewplayer.length;i++)
        s=s+mynewplayer[i]+"\n";
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Players are \n "+s);
```

Problem is that when it's written, it returns `null` for `mynewplayer`.
I suppose the `mynewplayer` doesnt really take the entries of the "myplayer" but neither writes the new username.

Compile doesnt show any errors. Just writes `NULL` to the textfile.

Ask me if u want further info on the code writen!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: time to do some debugging

Comment: This line `mynewplayer[x]=new Player(Username,Double.parseDouble(score));` x is being set to n+1, which will be out of index for the array

Comment: @EricG Thats what exception is telling me. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

True. But i need the second array to have one more entry than the one readen! any solutions??

Comment: @foutz `myplayer=new Player[n];` original of size n `int x=n+1;`
`mynewplayer=new Player[x];` new of size `n+1` If `n` is 10 then `x` will be 11. `mynewplayer[x]` is trying to access element 11 but the array's size is only 11 so the range is 0-10, not 1 - 11. This is why you are out of bounds.

Comment: @EricG  yes i think iam able to understand that but iam still newbie of solving this out :/ thanks for your help though.

Comment: @foutz I've added an answer with a bunch of changes to the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an edited version of your code, with some improvements and there should be a comment around code that I changed, explaining what I did.

```
    Player[] myPlayer = null;     // first word uncapitalized, every 
    Player[] myNewPlayer = null;  // other word begins with a capital

    //open Players.txt
    int i, n; // combine the variables into 1 line        
    String filename = "players.txt";

    try {

        FileReader fp = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fp);
        n = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
        // not needed
        //myPlayer = new Player[n];
        // NOT NEEDED int x = n + 1;
        myNewPlayer = new Player[n + 1];

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String s = bf.readLine();
            String user, score; // combine variables, doesnt need to initalize them

            String[] items = s.split(","); // Splits the line into array elements on every delimiter -> ,

            //user = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(","));
            //s = s.substring(s.indexOf(",") + 1);
            //score = s;
            user = items[0];
            score = items[1];
            // this line below isnt actually needed
            //myPlayer[i] = new Player(user, Double.parseDouble(score));
            // Create a new player clone, dont copy the previous one
            myNewPlayer[i] = new Player(user, Double.parseDouble(score));

        }

        // We've read all the variables from the text file, now we create the last one
        // Since myNewPlayer is (n+1) size, the range of the array is
        // 0 to n
        // the last index will be n                            New Score Variable
        myNewPlayer[n] = new Player("Username variable", Double.parseDouble("22"));

        bf.close();
        fp.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception was " + e.getMessage());
    }

    //----------------------------------WRITE mytxt!-------------
    // This is called a ternary operator
    // it is a 1 line if statement
    // the format is like so
    //   booleanLogic ? trueAnswer Execution : falseAnswer Execution;
    //         if ()  {       true          }else {         false  }
    n = myNewPlayer != null ? myNewPlayer.length : 0;
    // CHANGED HERE - was using the first array rather than second
    // dont need the 1st array
    try {
        filename = "players.txt";
        FileWriter fp = new FileWriter(filename);
        // Dont need "" before the items
        fp.write(n + "\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            fp.write(myNewPlayer[i] + "\n");
        }

        fp.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception was " + e.getMessage());
    }
    //----------------------------------WRITE mytxt!-----------

    //Get on Message
    String s = "";
    for (i = 0; i < myNewPlayer.length; i++) {
        // s += ""; is like doing s = s + "";
        s += myNewPlayer[i] + "\n";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Players are \n " + s);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot working on it. Works but instead of keeping the "old" files scores erases the last one score adding the new one! So if i open the app adding my username foutz with score 950. next time will be the new username i will put in only. "foutz" would be erased.

Comment: I tried doing it with an array list but it does the same job with ur code. Erases the last one adding the new one. i can post the code with the array list here instead of using two arrays if u want.

Comment: @foutz Change the ternary operator line to this `n = myNewPlayer != null ? myNewPlayer.length : 0;` I used the wrong variable. Also change the for loop below it `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {` n+1 -> n

Comment: and the funny is i changed n to myNewPlayer i figured it out but didnt change for loop. Anyway, u are AMAZING. Thanks a lot for ur HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is this:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         String s=bf.readLine();
         String user="",score="";
         user=s.substring(0,s.indexOf(","));
         s=s.substring(s.indexOf(",")+1);
         score=s;
         myplayer[i]=new Player(user,Double.parseDouble(score));

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                 mynewplayer[i]= myplayer[i];
        }
        mynewplayer[x]=new Player(Username,Double.parseDouble(score));
     }
```

You have nested loops, which is fine, but they use the same counter (the variable i ).

So what is happening is the first line of the file is read, and then added to myplayer[0]. However, instead of just also adding it to mynewplayer[0], you start another loop on i. This loop:

```
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                 mynewplayer[i]= myplayer[i];
        }
```

is going to copy the first player into mynewplayer[0]...and then null into every other entry (since myplayer only has the firsdt element filled.
The problem is that after that loop completes, i will equal n, so when you get back to the top of the outer loop, the check $i

Perhaps what you should do is this:

```
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         String s=bf.readLine();
         String user="",score="";
         user=s.substring(0,s.indexOf(","));
         s=s.substring(s.indexOf(",")+1);
         score=s;
         myplayer[i]=new Player(user,Double.parseDouble(score));
         mynewplayer[i]= new Player(user,Double.parseDouble(score));

     }
     mynewplayer[x]=new Player(<the new username>,Double.parseDouble(<the new score>));
```

Comment: U r right, well it doesnt work till but ur answer is a step to solution as i had nested loops too... problem is with arrays now. and their bounds. Thanks for ur help though.